# Post value change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have records which column name is counter. And the value is like 000003, 000012, and so on. But my problem is, when I try to post it the value that receive in the form action url change, I receive only 3 which is the real value is 000003. Why is that? I echo POST value in my second page.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
$result1 = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM app 
");
echo'<table border=1>
        <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>cc</th>
    </tr>
        </thead>';
        echo'<tbody>';
while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
echo'   <tr>';
            echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='javascript:postIt(".$row['counter'].");'>".$row['counter']."</a></td> ";
        echo'</tr>';
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";

?>
<script>
 function postIt(value){
   document.forms[0].id.value = value;
   document.forms[0].submit();
 }
</script>
<form name="blah" action="check.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id">
</form>
```

Why 000003 become only 3, or 000172 become 172. Help?

Comment: check your database data type

Comment: I check it, it's not integer, I set it in varchar

Comment: echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='javascript:postIt(\"".$row['counter']."\");'>".$row['counter']."</a></td> ";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may work

```
echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='javascript:postIt(\"".$row['counter']."\");'>".$row['counter']."</a></td> ";
```

Comment: it works, but would explain the function of \ that u add in the script?

Comment: in javascript function(0003) means function(3) but you need function("0003"). so i added ". but you already has " to handle string i need to escape it so put \"

Answer (score 0):

Because you are working with integers, not string. If you want to keep them as strings, meaning, with the leading zeros, convert the values to string type.

Comment: In the script? But how?

Answer (score 0):

Why is this a problem?  At the receiving end you can simply pad the number back out how you want it to.

It seems like a counter *should* be an integer.  You can then pad it out or not if and when you want to.

If you really want to you can pad it out before you send it.

See here:
[How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript)